# The onChange property reset the textfield every time when I type anything in the textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, firebase-authentication, material-ui

I'm trying to create a SignUp authentication page with firebase, So when I'm try to type anything in the textfield every time the text field got reset, I cant able to find the problem. But the main problem I found that with the "**onChange**" property. Please fix the issue why the textfield state change every time.
The SignUp page code:

```js
import React,{useState,useContext} from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import { styled } from '@mui/material';
import Logo from '../assets/QpiVolta-Logo.png'
import { useTheme,IconButton } from '@mui/material';
import { tokens } from '../theme';
import {Person,Lock, Mail, Visibility, VisibilityOff} from '@mui/icons-material';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { UserAuth } from '../context/AuthContext';

const SignUp = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
  
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const handleClickShowPassword = () => setShowPassword((show) => !show);

  const handleMouseDownPassword = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
  const [name,setName] = useState("")
  const [error, setError] = useState("")
  const {signUp} = UserAuth()
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const handleSubmit= async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
      await signUp(email,password)
      setError('')
      navigate('/') 
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      setError(error.message)
    }
  }
    const RootStyle = styled("div")({
        backgroundColor:"#d4cbf6",
        background:`${colors.primary[400]} !important`,
        height: "100vh",
        display: "flex",
        placeItems: "center",
    });
    const logoStyle = {
      height: '80px',
      
    };

    const CssTextField = styled(TextField)({
      '& label.Mui-focused': {
        color: `${colors.pinkAccent[500]}`,
      },
      '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
        borderBottomColor:  `${colors.pinkAccent[500]}`,
      },
      '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
        '& fieldset': {
          borderColor: 'grey',
        },
        '&:hover fieldset': {
          borderColor: `${colors.pinkAccent[500]}`,
        },
        '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
          borderColor: `${colors.pinkAccent[500]}`,
        },
      },
    });
    return (
      <RootStyle>
        <Container  maxWidth="sm" >
        <Box
          sx={{
            marginTop: 8,
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            alignItems: 'center',            
          }}
        >
          
          <img component="img" src={Logo} style={logoStyle}  />
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h2" color={colors.grey[100]} >
            Create an account<span style={{ color:`${colors.pinkAccent[500]}`}}>.</span>
          </Typography>
          <Box component="form"  onSubmit={handleSubmit} sx={{ mt: 2 , mb:2}}>
            <Grid container spacing={3} >
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} >
              <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
              <Person sx={{ color: 'action.active', mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
              <CssTextField  
                  fullWidth
                  label="First Name" 
                  id="FirstName"
                  name="FirstName"
                  autoComplete="family-name"
                  variant='standard' 
                  value={name}
                  onChange={(e)=> setName(e.target.value)}
              />
                  </Box>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
              <Person sx={{ color: 'action.active', mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
                <CssTextField
                  fullWidth
                  id="lastName"
                  label="Last Name"
                  name="lastName"
                  autoComplete="family-name"
                  variant='standard' 
                />
                </Box>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
              <Mail sx={{ color: 'action.active', mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
                <CssTextField
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  id="email"
                  label="Email Address"
                  name="email"
                  value={email}
                  autoComplete="email"
                  variant='standard' 
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    console.log(e.target.value); // add this line
                    setEmail(e.target.value);
                  }}
                />
                </Box>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
              <Lock sx={{ color: 'action.active', mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
                <CssTextField
                   required
                   fullWidth
                   name="password"
                   label="Password"
                   id="password"
                   autoComplete="new-password"
                   type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
                   variant='standard'
                   value={password}
                   onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                   InputProps={{
                     endAdornment: (
                      <IconButton
                        aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                        onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                        onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                      >
                        {showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                      </IconButton>
                     ),
                   }}
                />
                </Box>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              fullWidth
              variant="contained"
              sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
            >
              Sign Up
            </Button>
            <Grid container justifyContent="flex-end">
              <Grid item>
                <Link href="/Login" variant="body2" sx={{color:"grey"}}>
                  Already have an account? Sign in
                </Link>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Container>
      </RootStyle>    
  )
  }
  
  export default SignUp
```

Comment: Which textfield you are referring here?

Comment: The CssTextField  which is a custom styled textfiled

Comment: You have not added value prop along with onChange

Comment: please can you point it out? i've added target.value. Where is the problem i'm missing?

Comment: Added as answer. See last prop called "value"

Answer (score 2):

You should not put **CssTextField** and **RootStyled** components inside **SignUp** component. Put it outside and it works

```
import TextField, { TextFieldProps } from '@mui/material/TextField';

type StyledTextFieldProps = TextFieldProps & {
    colors?: any,
};
const CssTextField =
    styled(TextField, {
        shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'colors',
    }) <
    StyledTextFieldProps >
    ((props) => ({
        '& label.Mui-focused': {
            color: `${props.colors.pinkAccent[500]}`,
        },
        '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
            borderBottomColor: `${props.colors.pinkAccent[500]}`,
        },
        '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
            '& fieldset': {
                borderColor: 'grey',
            },
            '&:hover fieldset': {
                borderColor: `${props.colors.pinkAccent[500]}`,
            },
            '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
                borderColor: `${props.colors.pinkAccent[500]}`,
            },
        },
    }));

const RootStyle = styled('div')((props) => ({
    backgroundColor: '#d4cbf6',
    background: `${props.colors.primary[400]} !important`,
    height: '100vh',
    display: 'flex',
    placeItems: 'center',
}));

const SignUp = () => {
    const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);

    return (
        <RootStyle colors={colors}>
            <CssTextField
                fullWidth
                label="First Name"
                id="FirstName"
                name="FirstName"
                autoComplete="family-name"
                variant="standard"
                colors={colors}
                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            />
        </RootStyle>
    );
};
```

Comment: Then how can i use the theme hook and the colors hook? That will give another error.

Comment: @Rio you can check in my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-worker-fk4ekd?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Yup. This seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding value prop as well for each text field. Something like below

```
<CssTextField  
                  fullWidth
                  label="First Name" 
                  id="FirstName"
                  name="FirstName"
                  autoComplete="family-name"
                  variant='standard' 
                  onChange={(e)=> setName(e.target.value)}
                  value={name}
              />
```

do this for other text field as well where onChange prop is present.

Comment: ya I've changed according to this but now its only taking one input, after typing one input I've to manually select the textfileld to type another input!

Comment: Cant understand where is the issue coming from!

Comment: Hm. That's seems like a different issue now. You might have something which takes focus out after typing

Comment: yes! please help me to fix the issue!